# Не работает js-кнопка наверх во всех браузерах

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, анимация, frontend

Пока JavaScript не изучал, зациклился на тонкостях, фреймворках, препроцессорах CSS. Захотел скрипт для кнопки, которая плавно перемещает при клике пользователя наверх. Испробовал кучу скриптов - не один не работает(естественно, я id или класс из примера менял на свой). Скажу больше - тогда я скачал файлы примеров, и... они не работают. Ни в хроме, ни в файрфокс, ни в опере... НИ ОДИН скрипт не работает. В чём проблема?

Comment: Добавьте код JS/HTML которые не работают.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ты уверен, что скрипт был подключен?
2. Ты уверен, что `id` атрибут указан корректно и не дублируется?

   ```
   var goToTopButton = document.querySelector('#your-selector');

   goToTopButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
       window.scroll({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
   });
   ```